# How can I finish/distroy unwanted webview processes?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Guys I have been developing an application which is half native and half, and WKWebView based. The problem is, when I change the user from native side and login the system again with WebView older WebView continues working. Sounds are playing from older web. Also I can see it from Safari's developer tool.

```
self.webview?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: lastURL)!))
```

When I pick a another user from native side, then I get a session and I connect with new session on web, after setting new sessionID in cookie. I load the web again.

```
self.webview?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: lastURL)!))
```

I tried with notification&observer,

```
@objc func destroyWeb(notification: NSNotification){
        print("old webview is empty now") //debugging lol 
        self.webview.load(URLRequest(url:(URL(string: "about:blank")!)))
        self.webview.stopLoading()
}
```

But didnt help much. Let me show you how it is.

https://i.hizliresim.com/VQzALZ.png

Answer (score 0):

your older WebView still working because the older webview didn't call dealloc method.
you can add dealloc method to the webview code like

```
deinit {
        debugPrint("webview==>>deinit )")
    }
```

watch whether the webview didn't dealloc. If you do not want to use webview, you should released them

Comment: OK, I will try it. But can I make it work if it isn't working?